# Combine two potentially null lists with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists:

```
    var myIds = new List<int>()
        {
            1, 2, 3
        };

    var yourIds = new List<int>()
        {
            2, 3, 4
        };
```

The two lists can be combined into one like this:

```
myIds.Union(yourIds)
.Select(x => new 
             { 
                 Id = x,
                 Mine = myIds.Contains(x), 
                 Yours = yourIds.Contains(x)
             });
```

The new list would look like this:

```
Id    Mine     Yours
---------------------
1      T         F
2      T         T
3      T         T
4      F         T
```

This works great when the lists contain elements. However, what if the lists have the possibility of being null. How could I handle the null lists?

Comment: You mean `myIds` or `yourIds` is null? or it contains elements which can be null? (Latter is not possible in this case)

Comment: Both lists have the possibility of being null. However, they will not contain any null elements.

Comment: This exact same question was asked just yesterday by another user, they even where performing a `Union` on the code. Is this homework for a class?

Comment: I could answer it, but honestly it won't be any good than checking for null. If at all you need to avoid null checking create a helper method with does the null checks for you and return `Enumerable.Empty<int>()`

Comment: Yeah, I think it would be just as easy to check each list for null.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If the lists could be `null`, then you have to check for `null`. You can also use null coalescing operator and if any of the list is `null` then return an empty list *(internally [it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) will also check for null)*.

You can do:

```
(mIds ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>()).Union(yourIds ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>())
```

*(thanks to @phoog [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789121/combine-two-potentially-null-lists-with-linq/25789206?noredirect=1#comment40335029_25789206))*

**But IMO, it is better to check against `null`**

But if any of the list is empty, then you don't have to do any check, There will be no exception. Even if both the lists are empty , you will get an empty result back. The above code would return an empty list if any of the list is `null`.

Comment: You could use `myIds = myIds ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>();` to avoid the needless instantiation of new lists.  Replacing the null objects in the expression you give would not avoid a null reference exception in the lambda.

Comment: This works but as you mention it probably just as good to check the lists for null.

Comment: @phoog, that is a very good point. I don't remember seeing `Enumerable.Empty` before

Comment: Since you only need to Union() when both are non-null, a possibly more performant (and less elegant) solution could be to do myids != null && yourids != null ? myids.Union(yourids) : (myids ?? yourids ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>())... Especially as you often need to do additional stuff like Distinct() after Union().